# Validation Error Only one TargetTrackingScaling policy for a given metric specification is allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to autoscale dynamoDB but i am getting Error :

> aws_appautoscaling_policy.dynamodb_table_read_policy: Failed to create scaling policy: Error putting scaling policy: ValidationException: Only one TargetTrackingScaling policy for a given metric specification is allowed.

Here i am using only one TargetTrackingScaling policy .

Can any one help me regarding this ?

Below is code :

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "dynamodb_table_read_target" {
max_capacity       = "${var.as_read_max}"
min_capacity       = "${var.as_read_min}"
resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.log_table_name.name}"
role_arn           = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/aws-service-role/dynamodb.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable"
scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dynamodb_table_read_policy" {
name               = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization:${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id}"
policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
resource_id        = "${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.resource_id}"
scalable_dimension = "${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.scalable_dimension}"
service_namespace  = "${aws_appautoscaling_target.dynamodb_table_read_target.service_namespace}"

target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
predefined_metric_specification {
  predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
}

target_value = "${var.as_read_target_util}"
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can also happen if an existing stack's DynamoDB table has a `TargetTrackingScaling` in place.

To update it, you could remove the existing policy first and redeploy the scaling changes for DynamoDB.

Comment: How do you do this? I can't find where the policies live in the console.

Answer (score 0):

One Cloudwatch metric can only be used by one `TargetTrackScalingPolicy`. So if the metric you were referencing is being used by another policy, and you are using this metric again. It would show you this error.

Comment: Do you mean "metric" rather than "matrix"?